# CClientScript in yii

Tags: javascript, yii

As I am new to yii..I didnt understand what is CClientscript and its methods..

could you please anyone help me to about

```
CClientscript

registerScriptFile()

scriptFilePosition()
```

and its properties and methods

What is the use with this in yii..

what is the difference between

```
  $baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl; 
  $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
  $cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/jquery-min.js');
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl >/js/jquery-min.js"></script>
```

spent lot of time ..
please any suggestions ..thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

By using CClientScript class we can manages JavaScript and CSS stylesheets for views dynamically.

if you add direct script or css file, In you views or layouts in below format

`<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl >/js/jquery-min.js"></script>`

which mean, you are rendering file from view in static position.

By using CClientscript we can render jquery in different position, like inside Head Tag, in Body Tag dynamically and this class will generate script tag and it will append in your html dynamically with dynamic position.

Predefined position in CClientScript as per Yii Doc:-

```
CClientScript::POS_HEAD : the script is inserted in the head section right before the title element.
CClientScript::POS_BEGIN : the script is inserted at the beginning of the body section.
CClientScript::POS_END : the script is inserted at the end of the body section.
CClientScript::POS_LOAD : the script is inserted in the window.onload() function.
CClientScript::POS_READY : the script is inserted in the jQuery's ready function.
```

I hope, you got the information about CClientScript.